# Fill out datetime-local field with existing localdatetime object in jsp using spring form

Tags: java, spring, jsp

This is an editing form that will have all the fields filled out using existing data from database.  Regular text input fills out just fine but I am having issue doing the same with datetime.

```
<sf:form class="form-horizontal" role="form" modelAttribute="sighting" action="edit" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Reported Time" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">
               Reported Time:
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <sf:input type="datetime-local" class="add-form form-control" path="sightingDate" name="sightingDate"/>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, What is the issue ?

Comment: Right now the datetime-local field is default like : mm/dd/yyyy.  I want it to have the date and time that is passed in from the controller instead.  so instead of mm/dd/yyyy, it should say 11/11/2016 and allow user to adjust it if they need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the input type `date` instead of `datetime-local` since you don't have a timestamp part.
2. Modify your controller to populate your date in YYYY-MM-DD format
   (e.g. "2016-11-11") in the `sightingDate` attribute. You can't
   specify the date in any other format for an HTML5 date input type. You might want to make `sightingDate` as `String` so that you can store date in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` [attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value),

`<input type="datetime-local" name="sightingDate" value="sighting.sightingDate">`